# electron error AVDCreateGPUAccelerator: Error loading GPU renderer

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, electron

I'm attempting my first electron App. Does anyone know why i get this error `AVDCreateGPUAccelerator: Error loading GPU renderer` in the terminal when i do `npm start`?  It doesn't seem to effect anything yet.  I've gotten it right from the beginning of my install using the [quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) guide.  Will it effect me down the road?

mac pro late 2013
2.7 GHz 12-Core Intel Xeon E5
128 GB 800 MHz DDR3 ECC
AMD FirePro D700 6144 MB

Comment: Also seeing this. Same MacPro, same error.

Comment: Same error here. Just a speculation, maybe the FirePro don't support the GPU acceleration from Electron?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the AVDCreateGPUAccelerator error is because the Xeon CPUs used in the Mac Pros do not have a hardware decoder. Core i3/5/7 CPUs in Mac mini/iMac/Mac Book Pro) should work fine.

For a solution to this, please refer to the following answer;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57405820/10868666

Comment: I don't understand what the CPU has to do with it, when the error is complaining about the GPU.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? stuck on the same problem which basically means: "No Electron development on Mac Pro"... strange limitation...

Comment: @JonathanWylie Late comment reviewing old questions and answers. It all comes down to the GPU driver. Some hardware uses the GPU integrated in the CPU. Anyway, a solution is available in the answer referenced above.